# Heroku Error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - bs_fetch:open_current_file:open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

Devs!
I have an error, when I deploy my app to heroku. May you help me please how to fix it?

Error log:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - bs_fetch:open_current_file:open
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:51:in `fetch'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:51:in `block in install!'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/config/initializers/load_authentication_details.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_c3974d76/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --
```

**Assumption**

I have a yml file in config directory where I store some sensitive data.
I have a load_authentication_details.rb file in config/initializers for loading details(api_key) to rails app, with content:

```
AUTH_DETAILS = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/authentication_details.yml")
```

Perhaps the problem is in the content of this file(load_authentication_details.rb). May you help me please to figure it out?

Comment: Does this change anything: `YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'authentication_details.yml')`

Comment: The error is telling you the `yml` file doesn't exist. When you run `YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/authentication_details.yml")` in a development terminal, what do you get?

Comment: @Chiperific, Hello! The same error, if i write like You said in first comment. If in rails console i write AUTH_DETAILS the constant, it gives me the value of my api_key. And if i run YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/authentication_details.yml") in terminal it gives me error bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"#{Rails.root}/config/authentication_details.yml"'

Comment: the `bash:syntax error`: To run `YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/authentication_details.yml")` you first must be in a Rails environment. First run `rails console` then run the `YAML` command and see what happens.

Comment: @Chiperific. In rails console if i write YAML, it gives me `=> Psych`, if i run `YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/authentication_details.yml")` it give's me api_key like `=> {"api_key"=>"testtest"}`

Comment: So it's working as expected in development. This makes me think the file doesn't exist on production because you've blacklisted it in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @Chiperific, thank you very much! I thought about it, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, running in development you can successfully find the file:

```
$ rails console
> YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/authentication_details.yml")
=> {"api_key"=>"testtest"}
```

You can try this in a Heroku console (if you have the Heroku CLI installed on your computer):

```
$ heroku run rails console
> YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/authentication_details.yml")
```

But my guess is you'll get the same error: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - bs_fetch:open_current_file:open`

And, I bet it's because the file doesn't exist in production.
You said it's a file with a secret key. So you probably added it to your `.gitignore` file. This means it's not in your Git, it's not on GitHub, and it's not sent to Heroku when you deploy.

So your options are:

1. remove the file from `.gitignore` and it will be made public on GitHub and sent to Heroku when you deploy **DON'T DO THIS IF THE CONTENTS ARE SECRET**
2. If this file really can't be made public, you need to change strategies and use Rails's Credentials system and Heroku's Config Vars:
   https://www.viget.com/articles/storing-secret-credentials-in-rails-5-2-and-up/